# Is it possible to use grid layout to make a table with frozen/fixed header

Tags: css, grid-layout

The fact that grid layout allows me to build a table in CSS in a completely different way, I was trying to figure out a way to make a grid layout where the first row stays in view, whilst the rest scroll. Importantly without losing the grid behavior (a 'cell' with a lot of content should change the width and/or height of the entire column and/or row including the unscrollable first row).

Is this possible?

Comment: @Paulie_D So what, should I write you how you can make a grid in grid layout? Should I make a list of Google searches I did? I mean, I know that I am a low rep user, but so far I only wrote answers and I think they show well enough that I am not here to take SO as a code writing service. This question is along the lines of 'can I use this primitive to achieve a certain thing', the answer is likely no based on my understanding of grid layouts.

Comment: Like honestly, I am somewhat sure this hasn't been attempted before (based on my google searches) or is downright impossible. As far as my own understanding of grid layouts go it isn't possible either, but as this was one of the major problems with tables in HTML and grid layout is supposed to be solving the major problems with grids (a superset of tables) it seems a very reasonable thing to ask whether this is one of those problems it solved.

Comment: @Paulie_D Additionally, assuming you voted to close this question: I am in no way asking a 'fix my code' question. This is the minimal description of my problem: Can tool X solve known problem Y? I am not even asking for code, an answer saying 'Yes, using these and these properties and/or css functions' answers the question.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I recently came upon this codepen from [@Nicolas CHEVOBBE](https://twitter.com/nicolaschevobbe):

https://codepen.io/nchevobbe/pen/bYZEqq?editors=0110

It shows an example of what you describe. Fixed header row using grid layout. It's quite simple for a feature that takes a lot of effort to code otherwise.

The essential part is using position `sticky` on header cells:

```
[role=columnheader] {
  background-color: #F9F9FA;
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
  padding: 5px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #E3E4E4;
}
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: That's amazing :O

Comment: Adding to this answer: We were also looking for this but having more than one row sticky. It requires you to calculate the top css property for subsequent rows to get them to stick to above sticky rows.